# How to make code on an Azure VM trigger from storage blob change (like Functions do)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've got some image processing code that I need to run in Azure. It's perfect for an Azure Function, but unfortunately requires a component with a complex installation procedure and therefore will need to run in a VM.

However, I'd like to make it *behave* much like an Azure Function, and trigger whenever new items arrive in blob storage.

My question is: Does Azure provide me with any handy way of doing this, or do I have to write code that polls the blob storage looking for new items?

Comment: Have you considered a logic app that uses the HTTP action to notify your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Azure WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki). It shares API model with Functions, but you can host it in any .NET application. [Blob Trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Blobs).